# Good resource on ECMs/VECMs?

Tags: regression, references, vector-error-correction-model, ecm

I am trying to understand ECMs and VECMs and what the relationship between a regression model with stationary residuals or time series errors.  Is there a good website/book that goes into the assumptions behind the ECM and what makes it different from the regression model?  Also how the estimated coefficients and interpretation are related to each other.

Thanks!